# Javascript remove event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys i have a little problem , huge for me , so that is why i have to ask you ...
Anyway problem is , i want to copy table row from one table and add it to another table , but before i add it to another table i need to remove all of its events , i used google allot but its not helping me

```
var $UserRow = $(Final).closest('tr');

$('td', $UserRow).each(function () {
    $(this).onclick = null;
});

$UserRow.clone().appendTo($('#UserTicket'));
```

This is code so far , i got UserRow and all 'td's inside of it just how to remove all of its events?

Comment: use .off() http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they're not part of jQuery's event system, there's no reason to create a jQuery object.

You need to clear the native DOM element:

```
$('td', $UserRow).each(function () {
    this.onclick = null;
});
```

I'm not sure if the handlers will be recreated since you used event attributes, so you may want to clear that too.

```
$('td', $UserRow).each(function () {
    this.onclick = null;
    this.removeAttribute("onclick");
});
```

Comment: But i have tried that already , i posted it like that and it is not working , that is why i asked a question

Comment: @Veljko89: No you didn't post it like that. Look again. You're doing `$(this).onclick = null`. I'm doing `this.onclick = null;`.

Comment: I dont get it , i use firebug to debug javascript and im looking each line of code and i see there is no events on td's , but when it finish copying events are still there

Comment: @Veljko89: Wait, the handlers are on the `button` and not on the `td`? If so, why were you unbinding from the `td`? Change `'td'` to `'button'` if that's the case.

Comment: I just did that 2 min ago and i managed that part thanks so much for the help , but not second problem shows up ... it also removes events from original 'tr' not just cloned one. 
But thanks anyway for help guys

Comment: To use this method, you have to do *removeAttribute* and set the associated property to undefined (or null or whatever) for every possible intrinsic listener unless you know exactly which ones to remove.

Comment: @RobG yeah, this looks bad. I'm pretty sure `cloneNode` won't copy handlers unless they're written as attributes, though... am I mistaken about that?

Comment: Yeah i fixed that part because i know exacly which ones i have to remove , i used `this.removeAttribute("onclick");`
So just to add another function now `onclick` and my problem is gone

Comment: #GGG— *cloneNode* won't copy listners added using *addEventListener*, but it will copy those as inline attributes or added using *setAttribute*. Many libraries fallback to *attachEvent* for older IE, those listeners will be copied by *cloneNode*. So there really is no general way to remove listeners you don't know about. It might be simpler to create a new element and copy over just the attributes and properties you care about.

Answer (score 2):

You just need clone first and then append to the container. `.clone` doesn't copy the event handlers by default.

```
var $UserRow = $(Final).closest('tr').clone();
$UserRow.appendTo('#UserTicket');
```

***[jQuery.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)***

```
.clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents] )
```

> ***withDataAndEvents*** A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data
>   should be copied along with the elements. **The default value is false**.
>   In jQuery 1.5.0 the default value was incorrectly true; it was changed back to false in 1.5.1 and up.

Comment: Thanks for answering but it is still not working , it does clone events also , i also tried with putting  
`var $UserRow = $(Final).closest('tr').clone(false);`
but still no luck

Comment: The DOM Core `cloneNode` will copy inline listeners too.

Comment: @Veljko89 How is the event handler bound?

Comment: `<button class="x_normal" type="submit" name="<?php echo $rez?>"  id="2" onclick="GetInfo(this.name,this.id)">`

Comment: @Veljko89 Then you need to remove the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: i am with removing attribute as user1689607 said but it is still not working 
`$('td', $UserRow).each(function () {
    this.onclick = null;
    this.removeAttribute("onclick");
});`

Comment: Oh, and cloning will not remove listeners added using *attachEvent* (IE 7 and lower, perhaps higher in quirks mode).

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `.off`.

```
$(element).off('click');
```

Us the above to remove all click handlers. To remove only a specific click handler, do

```
$(element).off('click', functionNotToBeExecuted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this by using the DOM and `cloneNode`; you'll notice that event handlers don't get copied. For example:

```
// get the first table row in the document.
var firstRow = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];

// give it an event handler to test.
firstRow.onclick = function() { alert('It works'); };

// clone the row and append it to the end of the row set.
firstRow.parentNode.appendChild(firstRow.cloneNode(true));
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QtWGh/); you'll see that it clones the first row and appends it to the end of the table, and the row is no longer clickable.